# Non-saturated algebraically closed field

Tags: field-theory, model-theory

I've always thought of saturated models as a generalization of algebraically closed fields, viewing types as generalized polynomials.

I was wondering, in the particular case of (infinite) fields (thought of as models of the f.o. theory of fields), whether one can have an algebraically closed, non-saturated model? (The converse implication is obviously true.)

Looking at $\mathbb{C}$, $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{C})$ seems to be rich enough so as to guarantee saturation (although I'm not 100% sure of this), so that wouldn't work as an example.

Comment: Take the prime model, the algebraic closure of $\Bbb Q$, for example. In the case of $\Bbb C$, do note that the field is isomorphic to an ultrapower of itself, which is always saturated.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you for your comment. Do you have a reference for the ultrapower fact?

Comment: It follows immediately from cardinality + categoricity.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That should be an answer.

Comment: @Noah: Be my guest, I have a few other things on my mind at the moment.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ultrapowers are in general only $\aleph_1$-saturated, so I think you have to assume CH to prove that $\mathbb{C}$ is saturated (meaning $|\mathbb{C}|$-saturated) in this way.

Comment: @Alex: Aha. Can we get around this by absoluteness somehow?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Hmm... I think the question of whether a particular model is saturated is not absolute, so I don't see how to do this. But I'm a bit out of my depth when it comes to questions of forcing and absoluteness.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe @Noah can bridge that gap... :) (Also, I didn't mean that as a general argument, but rather as something specific for the complex numbers.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An algebraically closed field $K$ is determined up to isomorphism by its characteristic and its transcendence degree over the prime field. And $K$ is saturated if and only if it has infinite transcendence degree.

Fix a characteristic $p$ (prime or $0$) and let $F$ be the prime field ($\mathbb{F}_p$ if $p$ is prime, or $\mathbb{Q}$ if $p = 0$). For uncountable $\kappa$, there is exactly one algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$ and cardinality $\kappa$ (it must have transcendence degree $\kappa$ over $F$), and it is saturated. In particular, $\mathbb{C}$ is saturated.

Among countable algebraically closed fields of characteristic $p$, the possible transcendence degrees are $0, 1, 2, \dots, \aleph_0$. The fields of finite transcendence degree are not saturated, but the one of infinite transcendence degree is saturated.

*Proof:* Suppose $K$ has transcendence degree $n$ over $F$. Then $K\cong \overline{F(t_1,\dots,t_n)}$. There is a consistent type $p(x)$ with finitely many parameters $\{t_1,\dots,t_n\}$ expressing that $x$ does not satisfy any non-trivial polynomial in $F(t_1,\dots,t_n)$, and this type is not realized in $K$, since every element of $K$ is algebraic over $F(t_1,\dots,t_n)$, so $K$ is not saturated. For the converse, suppose $K$ has infinite transcendence degree over $F$. Let $p(x)$ be a type with parameters from $A$, with $|A|<|K|$. Then either $p(x)$ is algebraic (because it contains some non-trivial polynomial equation) in which case $p$ is realized in $K$, or $p(x)$ is the type of an element transcendental over $A$ (because it contains no non-trivial polynomial equations). In the latter case, since $|A| < |K|$, and $K$ has infinite transcendence degree over $F$, $K$ also has infinite transcendence degree over the relative algebraic closure of the field generated by $A$ in $K$, so we can realize the type in $K$.

These facts hold more generally for all uncountably categorical theories, with the notion of transcendence degree replaced by dimension of a strongly minimal set over the prime model.

---

*Extra comment:* I think the proper model-theoretic generalization of algebraically closed fields is the notion of existentially closed models, rather than the notion of saturated models. Of course, these two notions are similar in a lot of ways, but the important difference is that existentially closed models have solutions to conditions described by *quantifier-free formulas* (like a polynomial equation $f(x) = 0$), whereas saturated models have solutions to conditions described by *complete types* (which are much more expressive, e.g. a type $p(x)$ can say "$x$ is transcendental", which can't be expressed by a single formula). Indeed, algebraically closed fields are exactly the existentially closed fields, but they are not necessarily saturated.

Comment: Thanks! Quick question, if you don't mind: why is it true that "$K$ is saturated if and only if it has infinite transcendence degree"?

Comment: @Reveillark I added a proof sketch.