# How can I prove that every uncountable algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$ is saturated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory

The definition of saturated that I am working with is that for every subset of parameters of cardinality strictly inferior to that of the field, every type on that set of parameters is realized in that field.
I guess I should use somehow quantifier elimination or the fact that $ACF_0$ is complete, but I still have no good idea. Moreover, I don't know how I should use the fact that the field is uncountable, and I know that the hypothesis on characteristic $0$ is actually superfluous.

Comment: So: let $B$ be a set of parameters. What are the possible types over $B$?

Comment: @AlexKruckman They are all the possible sets of formulas in one (at least, for 1-types) free variable and parameters from $B$ such that every finite conjunction of them is realized in the field. However, because of quantifier elimination one can just consider types of formulas of the kind $p(x)=0$ or $p(x)\neq 0$, where p is a polynomial defined by parameters from $B$.

Comment: That's correct. How many such types are there? Can you find any examples that are definitely realized in the field?

Comment: @AlexKruckman At most $2^{\vert B \vert}$ types. One example of a realized type for a model, let's say $\mathbb{C}$,  would be one made only of formulas of the kind $p(x) \neq 0$, since the sets they define are cofinite and so the intersection of $ \kappa < \vert   \mathbb{C} \vert$ many of them is non-empty.

Comment: Ah-ha. Great! So the type which contains only polynomial *inequations* is realized in the field. On the other hand, what about a type which contains a polynomial equation $p(x) = 0$? Can you show that any such type is realized in the field?

Comment: Ok, now I see it. Let $a_1, ... , a_n$ be the roots of the polynomial. If the type is not realized that means that the intersection of the sets defined by the formulas is $\emptyset$. But then for each $a_i$ there is a formula $\phi_i (x)$which it does not realize. Then, if you take the conjunction $p(x)=0 \land \phi_1 (x) \land... \land \phi_n (x) $, it is not realized in the structure.

Comment: That's it! I recommend you write the above as an answer to your own question and accept it, so that the question is removed from the "unanswered questions" queue. For more information on saturation of algebraically closed fields, see my answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3514028/non-saturated-algebraically-closed-field/3514193#3514193 (Alternatively, if you think the linked post answers your question and you don't want to write up an answer, we could close the question as a duplicate of the linked one.)

Comment: Last comment: $2^{|B|}$ is an upper bound on the number of types over $B$, but in this case we can do better: When $B$ is infinite, there are exactly $|B|$-many complete types over $B$. Let $F$ be the subfield generated by $B$. For each irreducible polynomial $p\in F[x]$, there is a type determined by $p(x) = 0$ and $q(x)\neq 0$ for all polynomials $q$ which are not divisible by $p$. Since $|F[x]| = |F| = |B|$, there are $|B|$-many of these types. And then there is just one more "transcendental" type containing $p(x)\neq 0$ for all non-zero polynomials $p\in F[x]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F$ be our field. Because of Quantifier Elimination, we can assume that the type only contains equalities of the kind $p(x)=0 $ and inequalities of the kind $p(x) \neq 0$, where $p(x)$ is a polynomial such that its coefficients are closed terms taken from the constants $0, 1$ together with the set of parameters $B$ and functions $\cdot$ and $+$. Since these polynomials are $\vert B \vert$ many, if the type only contains inequalities, because of $\vert B \vert <\vert F \vert $ there are elements that realize every inequality. If, on the other hand, we have an equality of the kind $p(x) = 0$ in our type, and let $a_1,...,a_n$ be the roots of the polynomial. If the type is not realized that means that the intersection of the sets defined by the formulas is $\emptyset$. But then for each $a_i$ there is a formula $\phi_i(x)$ which it does not realize. Then, if you take the conjunction $ p(x)=0 \land \phi_1(x)\land ...\land \phi_n(x)$ , it is not realized in the structure.